# Scala, call instance method right from superconstructor call?

Tags: scala, super, method-call

Suppose I have the following Scala code:

```
class Foo(a: Int)

class Bar(b: Buffer[Int]) extends Foo (sum) {

  def sum = (1 /: b)(_ + _)

}
```

why does it complain on calling the method `sum` from the constructor? Is it not possible to get such a behavior with such simple implementation at all? I realize that I could make a companion object for `Bar` but that is not exactlywhat would I do?

PS there is no 'superconstructor' tag!)))

**UPDATE:** What are possible alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time an instance of `Bar` is being constructed all its members are being added to it. Only after the construction is complete can you call its members.

Comment: Ok, but what are any alternatives?

Comment: You can `class Bar(b: Buffer[Int]) extends Foo((1/:b)(_+_))`.

Answer (score 1):

if `sum` is not being called on a `Bar` instance -- and it isn't, since it hasn't been constructed yet! -- then its place is definitely *not* inside `Bar`. If `Bar` is its sole user, then the natural place for it is the companion object.

The more interesting question is why you don't want it in its natural place?

Comment: There is the following simplified example: imagine you have a class `Rule` which represents some rule applied to an object over a period of time which is called `duration`. There may be many children of that class, but I also want to have children like `RuleChain` and `RuleParallel`. These two classes may contain a set of rules executed sequentially or simultaneously, but treated exactly as `Rule`. As the `Rule` class takes `duration` as one of parameters, I have to pass the sum of durations for chain and the longest duration for parallel, thus I have to call some method.

Comment: @noncom What I don't understand is why you feel that method has to be in the class, not on the object, since it isn't about the instance.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just got used to think like that in Java, where there was no big difference. Here Scala enforces a more strict concern of application design and now I see it as a more correct one. With this in mind, it is obvious that the companion object is the best place for such methods.